# BufferedReader.read() requiring null in incoming data and not returning -1 on ending

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, bufferedreader

I am trying to do a simple TCPIP client and server (for the sake of testing now both are in the same server)program. Server reads the request and sends back an acknowledgement for the request.
I have been stuck with two issues

1. To my understanding BufferedReader.read() is supposed to read byte
   by byte and return -1 when no more data is available to read. I do
   not see the reading happening
2. BufferedReader.read() never completes the read loop.

To solve 1, when request is sent from client, I append a null character. Now I see the read is happening, but it does not come out if the read loop, still waits for more data. (line 96 in client program).

To solve 2, for read() I stopped checking for -1, and started checking for > 0.
(line 75 in server program).

Can someone explain me why this behavior ?

**Server program**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class TCPServer
{
        ServerSocket serverSocket;
        Socket clientSocket;
        DataInputStream is;
        DataOutputStream os;
        BufferedReader br;
        int Port;

        TCPServer( int Port)
        {
                this.Port = Port;
                try
                {
                        serverSocket = new ServerSocket( Port );
                }
                catch( Exception E )
                {
                        System.out.println( "Exception Socket : " + E );
                }
                System.out.println( "Server socket created" );

                try
                {
                        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                }
                catch( Exception E )
                {
                        System.out.println( "Exception accept : " + E );
                }
                System.out.println( "Client socket created and binded" );
        }

        public void initInOutStream()
        {
                try
                {
                        is = new DataInputStream( clientSocket.getInputStream() );
                        br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is ) );
                }
                catch( Exception E )
                {
                        System.out.println( "Exception InputStream : " + E );
                }
                System.out.println( "input stream stream created" );
                try
                {
                        os = new DataOutputStream( clientSocket.getOutputStream() );
                }
                catch( Exception E )
                {
                        System.out.println( "Exception OutputStream : " + E );
                }
                System.out.println( "output stream stream created" );
        }

        public void processTCPServer()
        {
                String clientRequest = null;
                String ServerResponse = null;
                byte[] clientRequestArray = {};
                try
                {
                        int intvalofchar = 0;
                        initInOutStream();
                        while( true )
                        {
                                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( 512 );
                                System.out.println( "Waiting for request " );
                                while( ( intvalofchar = br.read() ) > 0 )
                                //while( ( intvalofchar = br.read() ) != -1 ) 
                                        sb.append( (char) intvalofchar );
                                clientRequest = sb.toString();
                                System.out.println( "Client Request : " + clientRequest );
                                ServerResponse = "Ackn for [" + clientRequest + "]\0";
                                try
                                {
                                        os.writeBytes( ServerResponse );
                                        os.flush();
                                        System.out.println( "Sent" );
                                }
                                catch( SocketException E )
                                {
                                        System.out.println( "Exception " + E );
                                }
                        }
                }
                catch( Exception E )
                {
                        System.out.println( "Exception readLine : " + E );
                }
        }

        public static void main( String []args )
        {
                TCPServer obj = new TCPServer( 9999 );
                obj.processTCPServer();
        }
}
```

**Client program**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class TCPClient
{
        Socket clientSocket;
        DataInputStream is;
        DataOutputStream os;

        TCPClient( String IP, int Port)
        {
                try
                {
                        clientSocket = new Socket( IP, Port );
                }
                catch( Exception E )
                {
                        System.out.println( "Exception socket: " + E );
                }
                try
                {
                        is = new DataInputStream( clientSocket.getInputStream() );
                }
                catch( Exception E )
                {
                        System.out.println( "Exception InputStream : " + E );
                }
                try
                {
                        os = new DataOutputStream( clientSocket.getOutputStream() );
                }
                catch( Exception E )
                {
                        System.out.println( "Exception OutputStream : " + E );
                }
        }

        public void processTCPClient()
        {
                String clientRequest = null;
                String serverResponse = null;
                try
                {
                        while( true )
                        {
                                clientRequest = getData();
                                System.out.println( "Send [" + clientRequest + "]");
                                try
                                {
                                        os.writeBytes( clientRequest );
                                }
                                catch( Exception E )
                                {
                                        System.out.println( "Exception writeBytes : " + E );
                                }
                                System.out.println( "Data sent " + clientRequest );
                                System.out.println( "Waiting for response " );
                                try
                                {
                                        BufferedReader brs = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( is ) );
                                        int intvalofchar = 0;
                                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( 512 );
                                        while( ( intvalofchar = brs.read() ) > 0 )
                                                sb.append( (char) intvalofchar );
                                        serverResponse = sb.toString();
                                        System.out.println( "Server Response : " + serverResponse );
                                }
                                catch( Exception E )
                                {
                                        System.out.println( "Exception readLine : " + E );
                                }
                        }
                }
                catch( Exception E )
                {
                        System.out.println( "Exception readLine : " + E );
                }
        }

        public String getData()
        {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
                String request = null;
                while( true )
                {
                        System.out.println( "Enter : " );
                        try
                        {
                                request = br.readLine();
                        }
                        catch( Exception E )
                        {
                                System.out.println( "Exception readLine " + E );
                        }
                        return request+"\0";
                        //return request;
                }
        }
        public static void main( String[] args)
        {
                TCPClient obj = new TCPClient( "localhost", 9999 );
                obj.processTCPClient();
                obj.getData();
        }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing here that supports the headline claim in the title about requiring null in the input.

Answer (score 1):

> o my understanding BufferedReader.read() is supposed to read byte by
>   byte and return -1 when no more data is available to read. I do not
>   see the reading happening

BufferedReader reads characters. Period.

> BufferedReader.read() never completes the read loop.

It would keep executing in a loop (talking about your code) until the read method of the underlying stream returns -1, indicating end-of-stream.

If you want to test -1, shut the corresponding socket down.

Comment: I am sending a data 'hi'. So it should give me 'h', 'i', and -1 ?    It did not return -1. Do you see any reason why it is not ?

Comment: @libemv.so.1.0.1 - Check the last line of this answer. It'd have returned you the integer values of character read. You need to close the socket to detect a -1.

Comment: Did you mean close the client socket ? Yes I have tried it. When i kill the client program, then I see the data received at the other end. But my objective is to always get a response from the server so I cant kill the client ?

Comment: @libemv.so.1.0.1 - From what it seems, what you require should already be getting fulfilled! ISn't it? *But my objective is to always get a response from the server so I cant kill the client* ---> Keep on sending data from server side to keep receiving data on the client side. What do you want exactly? What are you not able to get, which you expected?

Comment: @libemv.so.1.0.1 - I'd suggest you to implement an alternate version of communication protocol, in which you'd, before sending the message, provide the length of the message! What you're currently doing will not help you with what you're trying to achieve!

Comment: In fact the server program will be later replaced with some other system where I don't have the option to add a null at the end of the response(you can see I am adding a null at the end of response message for the client read to happen properly). I understand the option of a putting a tcpip header which will mention the length of the data which follows. but I feel there should be some solution as the issue I notice seems quite simple.

Comment: thanks for your time. I appreciate it. anyways I will keep looking at it for some more time before giving up. 

Comment: did. finally I changed to length and data following method.

Comment: it's not the answer which helped me but your comment. so up voted the  comment.

Answer (score -1):

> `BufferedReader.read()` requiring null in incoming data

No it doesn't, and there is nothing in your question that supports this claim.

> To my understanding `BufferedReader.read()` is supposed to read byte by byte and return -1 when no more data is available to read.

No it isn't. It is supposed to return -1 *at end of stream.* See the Javadoc.

End of stream on a socket occurs when the peer closes his end. The peer hasn't closed his end because it is waiting for a response. So reading the request until end of stream doesn't make sense. You need an application protocol to define when to stop reading the request. This could be as simple as a line, or as complex as XML.

NB Don't write code like this, with a `try/catch` around practically every statement. Code that depends on the success of code in a prior `try` block must be inside that same `try` block. Start practising that and you will see that you generally only need zero, one, or occasionally two `try` blocks in a method.